# passing value in c#

Tags: c#, smpp

Dear All,
I am writing a smpp application using c# and Devshock protocol.Here the mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm method get the parameter "**e**" as a parameter on "**Devshock.Protocol.SmppClient.Deliver_SmEventArgs e**" and then using "e" we get rest of the value like:**e.Params.Body.Data_Coding** and **e.Params.Body.Short_Message**.

```
private void mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm(object sender,Devshock.Protocol.SmppClient.Deliver_SmEventArgs e)
        {
           string ShortMessage = mySmppClient.GetShortMessage(e.Params.Body.Data_Coding, e.Params.Body.Short_Message);        
           MessageBox.Show(ShortMessage);         
        }
```

**Now my question is:**

**How may i get the value Params.Body.Data_Coding and Params.Body.Short_Message without using "e" as a parameter**.It will be better for me if i get the values using any object or like this below structure.How i do that?

```
private void mySmppClient()
{
  //declare any object or any other way let abc

   string ShortMessage=mySmppClient.GetShortMessage(abc.Params.Body.Data_Coding, abc.Params.Body.Short_Message );
   MessageBox.Show(ShortMessage);

}
```

I shall be very much glade to those kind heart who help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in Advance
Riad

Comment: *Why* do you want to get the values without referring to *e*?

Comment: Does the method have to be without any parameters? Is that the problem?

Comment: i need to declare a method without any parameter..that's why..@Heinzi adn @Dyppl pls help

Comment: why would you need a method without parameters? There is nothing in this setup that seems to require that

Comment: Riad, please, provide the full context. Where do you intend to use this method, what are the requirements etc. Otherwise it's really hard to help you

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't seem possible, at least not in a "proper" way. While you could use instance or static fields to pass the method's parameters, that would be abusing the language, and you'd eventually suffer because of low code quality. Perhaps, of course, there's a different way I didn't think of.

Why not pass method parameters as parameters though? That's what they're there for!

Comment: could you please guide me using an example?if possible

Comment: @riad: No, for two reasons. Firstly, it would require a much deeper understanding of your current code and framework than I actually have, so I can't. But more importantly, I would never knowingly provide an example for bad code.

Comment: @riad: Perhaps, if you provide full context to why you _need_ this method to have no parameters, we could help you a bit further.

Comment: dear configurator,first thanks for reply, basically using those parameters i receive the SMS. so i need to call a method into a timer function which can check every moment that is their any SMS available.If i using this method then when i call the method then what parameter i send into the method?pls suggest..

Comment: @riad: The whole point of having an *event handler* (`mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm`) is that you *don't* have to create a timer that frequently polls for new messages. You just attach the event handler to the event of the SmppClient (something like `mySmppClient.evDeliver_Sm += mySmppClient_evDeliver_Sm`... I'm not familiar with the SMPP API) and your function gets called automatically when a new SMS arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the content of the message you want to show is coming in as part of an event, I doubt you'll be able to get it any other way. However, you can *store* the value as a member in a class, and reference the content of that class from elsewhere.